# Nginx rewrite for wordpress site not works

Tags: nginx

Here I have written Nginx rule to rewrite URL, Don't know where I'm making mistake.

**It should work:** whenever I will hit **URL:http://host.com/web/sitemap_index.xml** Nginx should rewrite it with **URL:http://host.com/web/index.php?sitemap=1**.

Adding my Nginx config below:

```
server {
    server_name 0.0.0.0;
    root /var/www/html;
    listen 80;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        rewrite /sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
        rewrite /([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|xml|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|ttf|mp4)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Any URI ending with `.xml` is processed by the last `location` block. Either move the rewrite statements into that `location` or move them into the `server` block.

Comment: Thanks for the response Richard, I tried to add `rewrite` part in last `location` block as well as `server` block but it doesn't work